# Google Map API - Marker not displayed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am testing Google Maps API and the code who's coming from the doc not working for me, as the marker is not displayed while I have no problem with the map.

```
function initMap() {
  var place = {lat: 48.1389729, lng: -1.935302};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('maps'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: place
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: place,
    map: map,
    visible:true,
    title: "Hi There",
  });
}
```

The function is created before calling the API with the callback.
What I am missing ?

Comment: The posted code works for me ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/1opbsjsf/)).

Answer (score 0):

Add in HTML after you script

```
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Comment: The OP stated "I have no problem with the map"

Comment: You code worked on my html.
Can you show complete code?

Comment: The original code is in the OP, there is nothing more. At least, the map is displayed. So no, it's not coming from the tag you add on your post.

Comment: Check 'marker' variable in code. Maybe you redefine it.

Comment: As I said, all of my javascript code for this page is in the OP. I've also tried to test in a JSFiddle and the problem is still the same